# Counting: How do I add a zero if a word does not occur in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, collections, count, counter

I would like to find keywords from a list, but return a zero if the word does not exist (in this case: part). In this example, collabor occurs 4 times and part 0 times.

My current output is

[['collabor', 4]]

But what I would like to have is

[['collabor', 4], **['part', 0]**]

```
str1 = ["collabor", "part"]
x10 = []
for y in wordlist:
    for string in str1:
        if y.find(string) != -1:
            x10.append(y)

from collections import Counter
x11 = Counter(x10) 
your_list = [list(i) for i in x11.items()]
rowssorted = sorted(your_list, key=lambda x: x[0])
print(rowssorted)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have not clearly written your problem and requirements,I think I understood the task.

I assume that you have a set of words that may or may not occur in a given list and you want to print the count of those words based on the occurrence in the given list.

**Code:**

```
constants=["part","collabor"]
wordlist = ["collabor", "collabor"]
d={}
for const in constants:
    d[const]=0
for word in wordlist:
    if word in d:
        d[word]+=1
    else:
        d[word]=0

from collections import Counter
x11 = Counter(d) 
your_list = [list(i) for i in x11.items()]
rowssorted = sorted(your_list, key=lambda x: x[0])
print(rowssorted)
```

**output:**

```
[['collabor', 2], ['part', 0]]
```

This approach gives the required output.

In python, to get the count of occurrence dictionary is popular.

Hope it helps!